# can we restrict the user to enter only one record using validation rule

Tags: validation

I just came across this question?

Can we restrict the user to enter only one record using the validation rule?
if the user tries to enter next record, it have to display an error message 'user limit exceeded'.

can we acheive this using validation rule, or we have to go through coding?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE - please see [tour] and [ask]. To clarify this question is this one record only per object for a specific object? What is the use case to have this restriction?

Comment: One record for Custom Object> Or record with same name of record, for example?

Comment: -1: Since your question is very vague. It could be, one record per object, one child record per parent record in child object, one record of same name or any other identifier in the same object.

Answer (score 0):

If this is one record per transaction, then it is a very easy trigger. The code would look something like:

```
if(Trigger.isNew and Trigger.isInsert){
  if(Trigger.new.size() > 1){
    throw new CustomException('User Limit Exceeded');
  }
}

public class CustomException extends Exception(){
};
```

If you mean one of a single record, then you can set the UserId into a custom field marked as a unique external identifier (set it as default value so that it always calculates).